# Is it possible to stop image errors from bubbling up to the console?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to stop image errors from bubbling up to the console?

I've tried the normal stuff - `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`

However, when I print out the Event to the console I get

[image]

and `cancelable` is set to false.  According to docs preventDefault will not work on events which are not cancellable.

My guess is b.c. you are wasting the network resources when looking for an image that is not there.  It is better to use some sort or maintenance algorithm to keep your links fresh.

Comment: Why would you need it? :)

Comment: Fix the site, not the symptoms.

Comment: It's just a personal preference, I don't like all the "noise" it generates in the console.

Comment: well, yea, I just needed a temp solution, until I can write an algorithm to stop the link rot.

Comment: Open filter. Check Regex checkbox. Add "GET " or whatever you want to filter out.

Comment: @return_of_the_drunken_coder Filter icon which is right next to clear console icon.

Comment: ....no also, this is a portfolio ... I don't want others to see this ...  I don't want to jack around with the console ... I will just fix the actual links ... not a problem.

Comment: OIC portfolio... :)  Then I do recommend to follow Niels' advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* your images were all loaded through some scripted mechanism, you could potentially test for image existence before actually loading the image -- putting a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on the `Image` `src` property, if necessary. Though, I suspect failed AJAX requests will appear in the log too -- so you'd need a single server-side script to accept and test the URLs for you.

But, apart from that special case, **it's not currently possible to scriptably intercept lower-level errors**. <sup>1</sup>

The only *conceivable* way to do this *in general* is to "jack around with the console", as you so-described in your comments. And, since your intention is to hide those errors from potential clients/employers, asking them to "jack around with the console" is clearly not an option. You're out of luck.

**Just fix the broken references.**

<sup>1. Well. It *may* be possible. But, if it *is*, you'll spend more time researching and architecting the hack than you will fixing your broken links. And it probably won't be cross-browser compatible.</sup>